# How often was the most frequent coupon chosen?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, coupon-collector

In the [coupon collector's problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/28906/6179), let $T_n$ denote the time of completion for a collection of $n$ coupons. At time $T_n$, each coupon $k$ has been collected $C_k^{n}\geqslant 1$ times. Consider *how often the most frequently chosen coupon, was chosen*, that is, the random variable $$C^*_n=\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}C_k^{n}.
$$

> Can one compute $E(C^*_n)$? What is a simple asymptotics of $E(C^*_n)$ when $n$ grows large? Does $C_n^*/E(C^*_n)$ converge in distribution and, if it does, what is its limit?

Note that $C_1^n+C_2^n+\cdots+C_n^n=T_n$. Since $E(T_n)=nH_n$ where $H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k$ denotes the $n$th harmonic number, such that $H_n=\log n+O(1)$, one has $E(C_n^*)\geqslant\log n$ and $E(C_n^*)=O(n\log n)$.

---

In a somewhat more ambitious version of this question, consider the nondecreasing rearrangement $C_{(1)}^n\leqslant C_{(2)}^n\leqslant\cdots\leqslant C_{(n)}^n$ of $(C_1^n,C_2^n,\ldots,C_n^n)$. Thus, $C_{(1)}^n=1$ and $C_{(n)}^n=C_n^*$.

Can one compute (or, get some simple asymptotics of) each $E(C^n_{(k)})$? And what is the "profile" of the random vector $(C_{(1)}^n,C_{(2)}^n,\ldots,C_{(n)}^n)$ when $n$ grows large? To be specific:

> Does the random vector $$\left(\frac{C_{(1)}^n}{C_{(n)}^n},\frac{C_{(2)}^n}{C_{(n)}^n},\ldots,\frac{C_{(n)}^n}{C_{(n)}^n}\right)$$ converge in distribution and, if it does, what is its limit?

**Edit:** Amy N. Myers and Herbert S. Wilf ([Some New Aspects of the Coupon Collector's Problem](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895480102403076), SIAM Review 48(3), 2006) provide explicit formulas for the distribution and the mean of the number $S_n$ of singletons. In the notations above, $S_n$ is the size of the set of $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$ such that $C^n_k=1$, and also the maximum of the set of $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$ such that $C^n_{(k)}=1$. Myers and Wilf show that, for every $i$, $$P(S_n=i)=i{n\choose i}\int_0^\infty x^{i-1}(e^x-1-x)^{n-i}e^{-nx}dx,$$ and they deduce from this the esthetically pleasing identity $$E(S_n)=H_n.$$

Answer (score 7):

Each coupon appears $\log n$ times on average.

If I treat the number for a single coupon as a binomial, the variance is also asymptotically $\log n$.

Now treat each of the counts as a normal variable $\mathcal N(\log n,\log n) $.

[Expectation of the maximum of gaussian random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables) shows the maximum of $n$ independent standard normal random variables to be around $\sqrt{2\log n}$, so the final answer would be 
$$\mu+\sigma \sqrt{2\log n}=\log n+\sqrt{\log n}\sqrt{2\log n}=(1+\sqrt2)\log n$$

Edit:

On the other hand, here is an argument that the limit is $e\log n$.

Treat each coupon count as an independent Poisson variable with parameter $\lambda=\log n$.  The tail of the distribution is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Properties) 
as $$e^{-\lambda}\frac{(e\lambda))^x}{x^x}=\frac1n\left(\frac{e\log n}x\right)^x$$
The chance that at least one coupon is inside this tail would be around $n$ times that.  So the probability moves from near-zero to near-1 when $x$ is near $e\log n$.

Comment: Thanks. This assumes the numbers of coupons are (even roughly) independent. Are they?

Comment: @Did: the upper bound in Sivaraman's answer in the linked thread doesn't use independence, is quantitative (it is true for all $n$, instead of being an asymptotic result), and only uses sub-Gaussianity (so one could work directly with the binomials, without having to justify the approximation by normals). Getting a upper bound would thus be not too hard, although one would still need to justify properly the approximation by binomials (that doesn't look too difficult). A good lower bound looks tougher.

Comment: @D.Thomine The second heuristics in this post and the simulations in John's answer both seem to infirm the (approximate) independence assumed in the first heuristics.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple simulation in Python 3:

```
import random

def completeCollection(n):
    #collects random "coupons"
    #in range 0,1,...,n-1
    #until each is encountered at least once
    #returns the list of counts

    counts = [0]*n
    collected = set()
    while len(collected) < n:
        coupon = random.randint(0,n-1)
        counts[coupon] += 1
        collected.add(coupon)
    return counts

def expectedMax(n,trials):
    #estimates the number of times
    #the most collected coupon is
    #collected while collecting n coupons
    count = 0
    for i in range(trials):
        count += max(completeCollection(n))
    return count/trials
```

I evaluated `[expectedMax(n,1000) for n in range(1,101)]` and obtained:

```
[1.0, 1.985, 2.79, 3.403, 4.052, 4.575, 4.784, 5.145, 5.45, 5.672, 6.008, 6.198, 6.515, 6.508, 6.765, 7.006, 7.074, 7.207, 7.466, 7.416, 7.534, 7.711, 7.812, 7.992, 8.049, 8.012, 8.268, 8.467, 8.408, 8.467, 8.604, 8.54, 8.779, 8.666, 8.804, 9.121, 9.076, 9.033, 9.179, 9.289, 9.344, 9.33, 9.479, 9.456, 9.601, 9.613, 9.644, 9.836, 9.693, 9.82, 9.886, 9.944, 10.044, 10.124, 10.161, 10.113, 10.039, 10.273, 10.334, 10.345, 10.317, 10.454, 10.519, 10.483, 10.491, 10.496, 10.617, 10.593, 10.719, 10.859, 10.885, 10.782, 10.858, 10.841, 10.87, 10.804, 11.005, 11.005, 10.993, 11.105, 11.092, 11.121, 11.106, 11.159, 11.198, 11.209, 11.291, 11.393, 11.444, 11.428, 11.395, 11.584, 11.533, 11.511, 11.545, 11.559, 11.601, 11.585, 11.61,11.617]
```

Plotted this looks like:

[image]

which looks somewhat logarithmic. It also looks somewhat like a square root, but I evaluated `expectedMax(1000,1000)` and got 17.835, which suggests that the growth rate is slower than a square root.

Comment: Nice, +1. This suggests that $E(C_n^*)/\ln n\to c$ with $c\approx17.835/\ln(1000)\approx2.58$.

Comment: @Did I ran `expectedMax(10**5,30)` and on one run obtained 29.833, which when you divide it by `ln(100000)` gives 2.59 -- which is greater than the heuristic 1+sqrt(2) that Michael came up with, but in the same ball-park.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question Michael's second heuristic (that the $C_1^*$ is approximately $e \log n$) is correct.  This follows from combining the observation that $T_n$ is with high probability very close to $n \ln n$ with a result of Raab and Steger (Case 2 of Theorem 1 [here](http://wwwmayr.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/personen/raab/publ/balls.pdf)) that gives precise asymptotics for the behavior of the most collected coupon at time $c n \ln n$.

This question was also asked at [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215664/the-coupon-collectors-earworm), and my answer there gives more details (in particular, why you should expect enough concentration around the mean to turn "with high probability" into a statement about the expectation).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I shall have a look at it.